# VideoJS-IMA Plugin - Play PostRoll Ad after 2 or more Videos

Tags: javascript, video.js, google-ima

Is there a way in videojs-ima plugin to play post-roll ad after 2 or more videos? By default, it plays the pre-roll ad before first video and plays the post-roll ad after first video ends. I want to play sequence of videos and want ads to play before and after the sequence. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of it as a preroll and a postroll, think of it as two separate ad requests with a single ad each. Once all your content videos have played, simply send out the second ad request and create a new instance of your IMA AdsManager to delegate ad playback.